# Questions about implementing the Comparable interface

Tags: java, comparable

I am teaching a Java programming class for the first time. My textbook uses `Comparable`, but I see most examples on the net use `Comparable<T>`. Are these using two different interfaces?

Related to this, when I write a compareTo() method in my Student class, the textbook uses

```
public int compareTo(Object other){
    if (! (other instance of Student))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be a Student");
    return name.compareTo( ((Student)other).getName() );
}
```

I see other examples of compareTo() like this:

```
public int compareTo(Student otherStudent){
    return name.compareTo( otherStudent.getName() );
}
```

Is this second construct what one should use if the Student class implements `Comparable<Student>`?

Finally, my textbook gives hints on how to write a general-purpose object sorting algorithm. I arrived at the following. It works, but gives "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning. Is there a way to write a "safe" general-purpose sorting algorithm?

```
private static void bubbleSortObjects(Comparable[] array)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean swapped = true;
    while (swapped && i < array.length - 1)
    {
        i++;
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j].compareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                Comparable temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: The `Comparable` interface is parameterized and the `compareTo` method  uses that type parameter.

Comment: Run to the generics tutorial, and read up on it. The interface is the same, but in Java 1.5 it was given generic abilities. Your textbook appears based on Java 1.4.

Comment: That would explain a lot. The textbook claims to be updated for Java 1.6, but maybe not all of it got updated...

Comment: `Comparable` (without the <T>) has been obsolete since 2004.  Please use a newer textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Just for help, a modern general purpose sorting algorithm would be:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSortObjects(T[] array)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean swapped = true;
    while (swapped && i < array.length - 1)
    {
        i++;
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j].compareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                T temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```